# Function that iterates through a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class LN:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

def list_to_ll(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    front = rear = LN(l[0])
    for v in l[1:]:
        rear.next = LN(v)
        rear = rear.next
    return front

def add_after(ll,value,new):
    for item in ll:
        if item == value:
            ll.insert(ll.index(value),new)
```

I am working on an iterative function named `add_after`. It takes linked list and two values, value and new. It mutates the linked list such that every occurrence of the value is now followed by new. For example:

```
a = list_to_ll([2,1,8,2,2,4,2,5,2])
```

add_after(a,2,-1) results in a referring to a linked list containing the values 1->8->2->-1->4->2->-1->5->2->-1->None.

add_after(a,2,2) for the original list in a results in a referring to a linked list containing the values 1->8->2->2->4->2->2->5->2->2->None.

plus( I am not allowed to use lists, tuples, sets, or dicts in my code)

use linked lists processing only

when I run my `add_after` it gives me an error:

```
add_after(ll,2,-1)
for item in ll:
TypeError: 'LN' object is not iterable
```

can anyone help me to fix my `add_after` function? many thanks.

Comment: Your linked list is not iterable meaning you can't use a for loop on it. You also can't use `insert` or `index` as `ll` is a `LN` not a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make `LN` iterable, by defining `__iter__` methods which yields nodes:
2. Make `add_after` link new node.

---

```
class LN:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

    def __iter__(self):  # yield all linked node (including the first node)
        node = self
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next

def list_to_ll(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    front = rear = LN(l[0])
    for v in l[1:]:
        rear.next = LN(v)
        rear = rear.next
    return front

def add_after(ll, value, new):
    for item in ll:
        if item.value == value:
            ll.next = LN(new, ll.next)  # Make new node and link after current node
            break
    # TODO: Handle not-found case.


ll = list_to_ll([2,1,8,2,2,4,2,5,2])
add_after(ll, 2, -1)
for item in ll:
    print(item.value)

# Prints 2, -1, 1, 8, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2
```

---

**UPDATE** after reading OP's comment => changing only `add_after` (manually loop through nodes):

```
def add_after(ll, value, new):
    node = ll
    while node is not None:
        if node.value == value:
            node.next = LN(new, node.next)
            break
        node = node.next
```

NOTE: I made `add_after` add only one node. I will leave it as your work to add multiple nodes.

Comment: thanks, but actually I am only allowed to make changes on add_after function, I am not allowed to define the iter function.

Comment: Great! So that's what `__iter__` is for! Can this be used in any class definition to make it iterable?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, Yes it is. Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Comment: @jiahuiding, I updated the answer which iterate manually (does not require `__iter__` change)

Answer (score 0):

`ll` is an object of user-defined class `LN`. It is not iterable like a list, hence a for-each construct would not work in this context.

The following would be the alternative.

```
def add_after(ll,value,new):
    item = ll
    while item is not None:
        if item.value == value:
            newnode = LN(new, item.next)
            item.next = newnode
            break
        else:
            item = item.next
```

Addressing the OP's concern on inserting at the *n*th occurrence, the following code can be also applicable:

```
def add_after(ll,value,new,occ=1):
    item = ll
    while item is not None:
        if item.value == value:
            occ -= 1
            if occ == 0:
                newnode = LN(new, item.next)
                item.next = newnode
                break
        item = item.next
```

The optional fourth argument determines after which occurrence should the new value be inserted. For example, `add_after(ll, 2, -1, 2)` adds -1 after the second occurrence of 2.

Comment: cool, it worked for the first value. but why it doesn't work for the rest? it seems to iterates through the whole list.

Comment: @jiahuiding:  *why it doesn't work for the rest?* Could you expand a bit on that? Is it not working for other inputs?

Comment: when I call add_after(ll,2,-1), ll =[1,8,2,4,2,5,2] it returns 1->8->2->-1->4->2->5->2->None  only the first 2 followed by the -1

Comment: @jiahuiding: Yes, that is what is supposed to happen: insertion after the *first* occurrence. If you want to insert at a different position, you may have to add an extra argument to the code. Would you want me to do that for you in *this post*?

Comment: ok, since I am not sure how to insert the value to more than one position.

Comment: @jiahuiding: I've made the addition, kindly refer.

Comment: oh...thanks, but I am not allowed to add a new argument as an input, which means your occ is not valid in this case...

Comment: the function has to follow the strict format add_after(ll,value,new)

Comment: @jiahuiding: Like I stated, the extra argument is entirely optional, the existing insert function `add_after(ll, 2, -1)` would still work. The code just adds an additional functionality.

Comment: @jiahuiding: You cannot add a value to an arbitrary position in the list without supplying where to add in the argument. Even Python list `insert` function contains only two arguments `index` and `object`. Similarly, `remove(value)` only removes the first occurrence of the value in Python lists. I'm sure my answer satisfies the requirements as mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using recursion. I've also added a helper method `flatten` to visualise the changes for when I was testing.

```
def add_after(ll, at_value, new_value):
    if ll.value == at_value:
        ll.next = LN(new_value, ll.next)
        if ll.next is not None and ll.next.next is not None:
            # skips over the newly added LN
            add_after(ll.next.next, at_value, new_value)
    elif ll.next is not None:
        add_after(ll.next, at_value, new_value)

def flatten(ll):
    if ll.next is None:
        return [ll.value]
    return [ll.value] + flatten(ll.next)

# Output
>>> a = list_to_ll([2,1,8,2,2,4,2,5,2])
>>> flatten(a)
[2, 1, 8, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2]
>>> add_after(a, 2, -1)
>>> flatten(a)
[2, -1, 1, 8, 2, -1, 2, -1, 4, 2, -1, 5, 2, -1]
>>> b = list_to_ll([2,1,8,2,2,4,2,5,2])
>>> add_after(b, 2, 2)
>>> flatten(b)
[2, 2, 1, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Hi, when I test your code, it seems that it only add the new_value to the first at_value that appears.

Comment: Ah, I see, it fails when adding a value after the same value. `add_after(a, 2, 2)` I'll get on that.

Comment: thanks, now it seems to work for the first two values, when I call add_after_r(ll,2,-1) to the ll = [1,8,2,4,2,5,2] it returns  1->8->2->-1->4->2->-1->5->2->None  and when I call add_after_r(ll,2,-1) to the ll = [2,2,1,8,2,4,2,5,2] it returns 2->-1->2->-1->1->8->2->4->2->5->2->None

Comment: Can you explain to me why it does not work for the rest of the values? I am a little confused.

Comment: I get the correct output `a = list_to_ll([2,2,1,8,2,4,2,5,2]); add_after(a, 2, -1); print(flatten(a)) -> [2, -1, 2, -1, 1, 8, 2, -1, 4, 2, -1, 5, 2, -1]`. Have you copied the code correctly?

Comment: yes, I think I did, does it matter if I did not add your flatten function? since I am not allowed to add helper function in my code.

Comment: `flatten` was just added to easily check the values in the linked list. I suggest using it, if it gives you the correct output then there is something wrong with how you were checking your values.